# Internal server error when DEBUG=False in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

**hello you beautiful people!**

As soon as I set `DEBUG=False`, my website returns an internal server error. Going to /admin works, and I see the admin panel, however without any static files (CSS, JS) applied.

**the error I am getting:**

```
[14/Sep/2023 10:47:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 369
```

With `DEBUG=True`, I get no errors whatsoever.

**I have already tried:**

- redefining STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT in production.py as detailed [here](https://bestprogrammingblogs.blogspot.com/2021/03/django-static-files-not-working-when-debug-is-false.html)
- running collectstatic (in my pythonanywhere console, where my website is deployed. if I run the command locally and then push the code to pythonanywhere, I additionally get a merge conflict because the static files manifest cannot be found).
- setting up logging in my base.py. The resulting logfile contains no errors, only a lot of lines like the below:

*[13/Sep/2023 14:10:50] DEBUG [django.utils.autoreload:394] File /home/username/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail_localize/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/djangojs.mo first seen with mtime 1692563590.7096848*

**path of the favicon:**
mysite\static\img\favicon.ico

**from base.html:**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'img/favicon.ico' %}" />
```

**from base.py:**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static"),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Very thankful for any pointers!!

Comment: What does your web server error log say for that request? And how are you serving the static files? You tagged this PythonAnywhere, have you set up the static files mapping mentioned in https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles#set-up-a-static-files-mapping?

Comment: My web server error log reads internal error only. Static files are served directly from PythonAnywhere. I figured out that it was actually my ALLOWED_HOSTS setting that was at fault. I do not understand why but with DEBUG=True it gave no errors with ALLOWED_HOSTS including mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com, myuser.eu.pythonanywhere.com and www.myuser.eu.pythonanywhere.com. With DEBUG=False I had to set =['*'] for now because I am unsure what else to add, but now it works!

Comment: The error log would not just have "Intternal error" it should also include a traceback that you can use to debug.